# vbscript traverse through xml node- dynamic if else, node count detection

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

```
    myXML=      "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=iso-8859-1 ?>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<shippingRates code=fedex >" & vbcrlf & _
            "<errorMsg>" & vbcrlf & _
            "Sorry, no rates returned." & vbcrlf & _
            "</errorMsg>" & vbcrlf & _
            "</shippingRates>" & vbcrlf & _

            "<shippingRates code=CUSTOM >" & vbcrlf & _

            "<shippingRate index=0 >" & vbcrlf & _
            "<TotalRate>0.29</TotalRate>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<HandlingFee>0.00</HandlingFee>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<DisplayHandlingFeeOpt>1</DisplayHandlingFeeOpt>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<shippingMethod>shipping option 1 </shippingMethod>" & vbcrlf & _
            "</shippingRate>" & vbcrlf & _

            "<shippingRate index=1 >" & vbcrlf & _
            "<TotalRate>2.91</TotalRate>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<HandlingFee>43.69</HandlingFee>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<DisplayHandlingFeeOpt>1</DisplayHandlingFeeOpt>" & vbcrlf & _
            "<shippingMethod>shipping option 2 </shippingMethod>" & vbcrlf & _
            "</shippingRate>" & vbcrlf & _

            "</shippingRates>" & vbcrlf



    Dim oXML: Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")    
    oXML.loadXML(myXML)         'to load from string directly
```

Based on the xml Pattern scenario study.

I would like to achieve the following:

read if the node is 'fedex'
if yes, then count how many  node exist
if count>0, then loop into to get value of each node inside  (eg: shippingMethod, TotalRate)
if count=0, do nothing.

read if the node is 'CUSTOM'
if yes, then count how many  inside
if count>0, then loop into to get value of each node inside  (eg: shippingmethod, TotalRate)
if count=0, do nothing.

```
    iItem= 0


    set shippingRates_node = oXML.getElementsByTagName("shippingRates")

    for each itemNodes in shippingRates_node(0).ChildNodes


    set shippingRate_node = oXML.getElementsByTagName("shippingRate")

    if code= "fedex" then
        how to count?


        if count>0 then

            for each item in itemNodes.ChildNodes

                    if item.nodeName = "shippingMethod" Then                        
                            strItemLine= strItemLine & "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME" & iItem) & "=" & Server.URLEncode(item.Text)
                    end if                  

                    if item.nodeName = "shippingRate" Then
                            strItemLine= strItemLine & "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT" & iItem) & "=" & Server.URLEncode(item.Text)
                    end if                      
            next


            iItem= iItem + 1


        end if

    end if



    if code= "CUSTOM" then
        how to count?


        if count>0 then

            for each item in itemNodes.ChildNodes

                    if item.nodeName = "shippingMethod" Then                        
                            strItemLine= strItemLine & "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME" & iItem) & "=" & Server.URLEncode(item.Text)
                    end if                  

                    if item.nodeName = "shippingRate" Then
                            strItemLine= strItemLine & "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT" & iItem) & "=" & Server.URLEncode(item.Text)
                    end if                      
            next


            iItem= iItem + 1


        end if

    end if



    Next


TotalShippingOptions= iItem
```

Anyone know a complete solution to this?

Comment: Why URLEncode, are you sure you shouldn't be using HTMLEncode?  What do you do with the final string? You don't seem to be doing anything with strItemLine?

Comment: Also you XML is badly formed you can only have one node at the top level of the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you've tidied up that XML so that it has containing root node and the attribute values are enclosed in "".  My guess is this is what you are really after:-

```
Dim oXML: Set oXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")    
oXML.loadXML(myXML)         '' # to load from string directly     
Dim iItem : iItem = 0
Dim shippingMethod, totalRate
Dim strItemLine : strItemLine = ""
Dim rate

For Each rate In oXML.documentElement.selectNodes("shippingRates/shippingRate")
  shippingMethod = rate.selectSingleNode("shippingMethod").Text
  totalRate = rate.selectSingleNode("TotalRate").Text
  strItemLine = strItemLine & "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME" & iItem) & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shippingMethod)
  strItemLine = strItemLine & "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT" & iItem) & "=" & Server.URLEncode(totalRate)
  iItem = iItem + 1
Next
```

From the code you provided there was no actual disctinction between Fedex and CUSTOM hence th code is significantly simplified.

Comment: hi ya, the reason of this is, fedex's output, sometimes will have rate, sometimes won't have rate. If rate not found, will show the <errorMsg> . However I need to combine both result into strItemLine, which is a full string- for me to post to other website service.

Comment: Most likely the rate node at that point doesn't have a "shippingMethod" or "TotalRate" element, check your XML and note the comparisons are case sensitive.